# Optimal Way of Verifying a 3D Mesh Convex

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, convex-optimization, convex, convex-polygon

There are numerous questions on stack overflow similar to this problem already, but most are creating a convex hull, or checking in 2D Space.

I already have created an algorithm to create a 3D Convex Hull given the original Mesh's vertices, and checking if the final hull is identical to the original. However, its pretty inefficient, and I was wondering if there was some optimal way of verifying the convexity of the original.

[image]

Comment: Is there a faster 2D Method?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092577219800039X is an interesting article that pertains to the subject